# Ping TimeOut Issue

Tags: c#, timeout, ping

I have the following code...

```
 Ping ping = new Ping();
    PingReply replay = ping.Send(ipAddress, timeOut* 1000);
```

I run the function with the machine with the IP still turned off, and with timeOut set to about 5 minutes. I also have a CMD window open where I write ping ipaddress -t

Whilst the computer is still off I am getting time out's in both the CMD windows and from my program.

#### After about a minute

I turn the computer with the IP address on.

The CMD window immediately detects the machine and I get the address in the ping response address but I have to wait for the entire timeout to expire to get the address from the .NET function.

Why doesn't it reply immediately when the ping is OK like in the CMD?

Answer (score 1):

so I decided to write my own ping() for this purpose.

```
private PingReply ping(int tout,bool waitForSuccess)
{
    PingReply replay = null;
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    Stopwatch stopWatch=new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    long timeOut=tout*1000;
    while (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < timeOut)
    {
        replay = ping.Send(m_device.IPAddress,2000);
        if((replay.Status == IPStatus.Success) == waitForSuccess)
            break;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    return replay;
}
```